# Are $p$-adic groups also Lie groups? What is a $p$-adic group specifically?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I am a bit confused by the definition of a $p$-adic group. I initially thought that a $p$-adic group was simply a group with $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as the underlying manifold, however this seems to be too vague, as I have seen definitions that mention Galois groups, local Archimedian fields, etc... I have also noticed that these groups seem closely related to typical Lie groups, like $GL_n ({\mathbb{R}})$. My question is, are $p$-adic groups also Lie groups? Also, does anyone know of a reputable textbook with a concise and self-contained definition of a $p$-adic group?

Thanks

Comment: Concerning $GL_n(\Bbb Q_p)$, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572071/p-adic-representation-and-p-adic-analytic-group-p-adic-lie-group). Then, a book is [this one](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642211461). Do a search yourself!

Comment: I think there's no formal notion of "$p$-adic group". It might be a sloppy way to mean a "$p$-adic Lie group", or an algebraic $\mathbf{Q}_p$-group, which is not exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe pro-$p$-groups would count too?